# Java method: passing objects without defining them

Tags: java, processing

I am creating a new method, which shall be supplied with the array of objects.
However, objects are in the separate class, and I don't want to describe them in this on. So, how can I write a method without describing the classes I feed?

```
public void DO(object[] Balls){
 ...
}
```

Comment: Use the `import` statement to import the other class; Use `interface`s or even generics...

Comment: Your question doesn't make a ton of sense, and I think the people suggesting generics are misunderstanding what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by "describing the classes"? What's wrong with the code you've posted? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, the full story is that: I am writing an applet in Processing_Py (Jython), and My BALL class is described there. Therefore, I cant (?) refer to it in my "pure java" code, and JAVAC reject to compile  the example above as it has no idea, what is *the ball*. Therefore, for now, I have to "serialise" each ball into array of several values I need to the function for now... Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Use generics in your method like below

```
public <T> void DO(T[] balls) {
  ...
}
```

Here the beauty is not only objects of your class can be passed here, in the future objects of any other class can be passed without modifying this method. If you need some reference on generics, one of the below links should help you

> 1. [Journal Dev on Generics](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-tutorial-example-class-interface-methods-wildcards-and-much-more)
> 2. [Jakob Jenkov's](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/index.html)
> 3. [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to create a generic method.

```
public <T> void DO(<T>[] Balls){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following code:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

     public Class<T> Balls;

     public void Do(Class<T> Balls) {
          ...

     }

}
```